# Mongodb: Cannot query using first key, after importing data from csv file

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongodb-query

This is weird scenario for me. I have imported csv data into my mongodb collection and I couldn't query using its first key. Its allowing me to query using any other keys in the document except first key. This is my sample dataset.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e488f2eeac8616db281a7b"), "﻿event_name" : "pageload", "id" : 1658, "date" : 1451610622, "Browser" : "Chrome", "Device" : "Computer", "OS" : "Mac OS", "Country" : "Singapore", "City" : "Singapore", "Referrer" : "blog", "utm_source" : "", "utm_medium" : "", "utm_campaign" : "", "page_name" : "category", "firstvisit_date" : 1451610618, "item_name" : "", "quantity" : "", "item_price" : "", "bill_amount" : "", "fail_reason" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e488f2eeac8616db281a7c"), "﻿event_name" : "pageload", "id" : 1658, "date" : 1451610624, "Browser" : "Chrome", "Device" : "Computer", "OS" : "Mac OS", "Country" : "Singapore", "City" : "Singapore", "Referrer" : "category", "utm_source" : "", "utm_medium" : "", "utm_campaign" : "", "page_name" : "product", "firstvisit_date" : 1451610618, "item_name" : "", "quantity" : "", "item_price" : "", "bill_amount" : "", "fail_reason" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e488f2eeac8616db281a7d"), "﻿event_name" : "pageload", "id" : 4391, "date" : 1451611043, "Browser" : "Explorer", "Device" : "Mobile", "OS" : "iOS", "Country" : "Indonesia", "City" : "Medan", "Referrer" : "Google", "utm_source" : "Google", "utm_medium" : "cpc", "utm_campaign" : "g2", "page_name" : "homepage", "firstvisit_date" : "", "item_name" : "", "quantity" : "", "item_price" : "", "bill_amount" : "", "fail_reason" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e488f2eeac8616db281a7e"), "﻿event_name" : "pageload", "id" : 4391, "date" : 1451611045, "Browser" : "Explorer", "Device" : "Mobile", "OS" : "iOS", "Country" : "Indonesia", "City" : "Medan", "Referrer" : "homepage", "utm_source" : "", "utm_medium" : "", "utm_campaign" : "", "page_name" : "blog", "firstvisit_date" : 1451611043, "item_name" : "", "quantity" : "", "item_price" : "", "bill_amount" : "", "fail_reason" : "" }
```

When I query for

> db.dataset.find({event_name: 'pageload'})

its always giving empty result. But if I insert manually some data, I am getting that result. I tried to rename the key with below command

> > db.dataset.update({}, {$rename:{"event_name":"event"}}, false, true);
>
> WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 2001, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

Its showing nMatched correctly but again only updating my manually inserted data, not others. Its strange for me, any known issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running into TOOLS-879 bug which is fixed in latest 3.2 and 3.4 versions.